# compare content of two variables in bash

Tags: bash, diff

I have a variable `$data` and variable `$file` in a bash script:

```
data=$(echo "$(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]/%/$'\n\n'}")")
file=$(<scriptfile_results)
```

Those variables will contain text. How to compare those two? One option is to use *diff*(1) utility like this:

```
diff -u <(echo "$data") <(echo "$file")
```

Is this an correct and elegant way to compare content of two variables? In addition how is the `<( )` technique called? As I understand, for each `<( )` a temporary file(named pipe) is created..

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Yes, `diff <(echo "$foo") <(echo "$bar")` is fine.

By searching the [bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for the characters `<(`, you can find that this is called “process substitution.”

You don't need to worry about the efficiency of creating a temporary file, because the temporary file is really just a pipe, not a file on disk. Try this:

```
$ echo <(echo foo)
/dev/fd/63
```

This shows that the temporary file is really just the pipe “file descriptor 63.” Although it appears on the virtual `/dev` filesystem, the disk is never touched.

The actual efficiency issue that you might need to worry about here is the ‘process’ part of “process substitution.” Bash forks another process to perform the `echo foo`. On some platforms, like Cygwin, this can be very slow if performed frequently. However, on most modern platforms, `fork`ing is pretty fast. I just tried doing 1000 process substitutions at once by running the script:

```
echo <(echo foo) <(echo foo) ... 997 repetitions ... <(echo foo)
```

It took 0.225s on my older Mac laptop, and 2.3 seconds in a Ubuntu virtual machine running on the same laptop. Dividing by the 1000 invocations, this shows that process substitutions takes less than 3 milliseconds—something totally dwarfed by the runtime of `diff`, and probably not anything you need to worry about!

Comment: thank you for explaining this! On my Xeon X3220@2.40GHz 'time for i in {0..1000}; do echo <(echo foo); done' took 0.264s.

Comment: Note that even `echo foo > foo; cat foo; rm foo` is also unlikely to ever touch the disk.  If the tempfile is removed before the vfs is flushed to the physical partition, nothing ever goes to the platter.

Comment: Your echos need -e on the first line. Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: @thebunnyrules I don’t think `-e` would be helpful here, as it would make the literal strings `foo\tbar` and `foo bar` compare equal even though they’re different strings of different lengths. Did you have some an example in mind?

Comment: @andrewdotn, I was under the mistaken impression that it's needed to expand newlines in variable but I played around with echo yesterday and it's not. It's only needed for expanding user added newlines and tabs such as \n or \t but not the newline that a variable would inherit from being defined via  var=$(some operation). If I could withdraw the edit I would but once it's submitted it's out of my control.  Feel free to reject it.

Comment: @thebunnyrules No worries, glad you got that sorted out. One easy way to get a raw newline in a bash variable is to use a multi-line string literal; on line 1, `foo="bar`, then on line 2, `baz"`.

Answer (score 7):

```
test "$data" = "$file" && echo the variables are the same
```

If you wish to be verbose, you can also do:

```
if test "$data" = "$file"; then
  : variables are the same
else
  : variables are different
fi
```

Comment: is there a way to actually use `diff` on 2 variables instead of 2 files without writing them to temp files? I've actually wondered about that before. (so you can actually see what's different between them)

Comment: @sampson-chen as far I know, there isn't. However, it would be great if some experienced bash programmer confirms this.

Answer (score 6):

This works best for me:

```
var1="cat dog mule pig"
var2="cat dog ant"

diff <( echo "$var1" ) <( echo "$var2" )
```

First I set var1 and var2. Then I diff with <( ) elements to say that the input is a variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
~ cat test.sh   

#!/usr/bin/env bash

array1=(cat dog mule pig)
array2=(cat dog ant)

diff -ia --suppress-common-lines <( printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}" ) <( printf "%s\n" "${array2[@]}" )
```

Comment: you can operate with result, create variable and so on. my version prints out a difference, for example. just try it. will not harm.

Answer (score 3):

Using `comm`:

```
comm -23 <(echo $variableA | tr ' ' '\n' | sort) <(echo $variableB | tr ' ' '\n' | sort)
```